# How to import with typescript an exported const in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I'm using typescript 2.6.1. I'm using react-table and in its index.js file, it declares:

```
import defaultProps from './defaultProps'
import propTypes from './propTypes'

export const ReactTableDefaults = defaultProps
export default class ReactTable extends Methods(Lifecycle(Component)) ...
```

In my typescriptfile, I would like to use the ReactTableDefaults member, but I don't know how to access it. I already have an import for the react-table types defined in their @types/react-table/index.d.ts file. When I try to access the ReactTableDefaults, intellij can't find it. Could someone help me find the right import statement?

```
import ReactTable, {Column as RTColumn} from 'react-table'; //gets stuff from index.d.ts
import RT = require('react-table'); // can only see 'default'
```

I've also tried

```
import ReactTableDefaults from 'react-table';
```

But the ts transpiler just says that ReactTableDefaults can't be found.

EDIT: The ReactTableDefaults is not defined in the index.d.ts file. I'm trying to get it from the module file.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the external definitions make available under `ReactTableDefaults` do the following:

```
import * as ReactTableDefaults from 'react-table';
```

Afterwards you can it access like `ReactTableDefaults.myAttribute`.

but **NOTE:**

this may result in an unwanted effect: If the imported sources contained an attribute like the one you are importing `as` you need to access it like `ImportedAsThisName.ImportedAsThisName`, i.e.:

```
import * as MyLib from 'my-lib'
//assuming that the "MyLib" library had an attribute like "methodA" you'd access it like MyLib.methodA
```

but imagine the following:

```
import * as methodA from "my-lib"
```

to access the `methodA` attribute you'd now need to do somethink like:

```
methodA.methodA()
```

i hope this is clear.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had tried that. If I put 
    
    import * as RT from 'react-table';
    const defaultProps = RT.ReactTableDefaults;

It doesn't recognize ReactTableDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

`ReactTableDefaults` is a named export. The attempt you have at the end of your question is trying to import it as though it were the default import instead.

Assuming you're seeing `index.js` as `'react-table'`, then you can add it to your `import`:

```
import ReactTable, {Column as RTColumn, ReactTableDefaults} from 'react-table';
// -----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...or do it on its own if you prefer:

```
import {ReactTableDefaults} from 'react-table';
```

Comment: When I do that, the transpiler tells me: TS2339: Property 'ReactTableDefaults' does not exist on type 'typeof "node_modules/@types/react-table/index"'.

Comment: @kim: Sounds like the `.d.ts` file is missing it (intentionally or otherwise).

Comment: Yes, it is missing it, but I know I can import it from the module file - I've done it before but I lost my changes and I don't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I had before (given to me by a colleague), but I didn't remember that it was so hacky.

```
import * as RT from 'react-table';

const defaultProps = (RT as any).ReactTableDefaults;
```